# Problems with TouchableOpacity not working with position:"absolute"

Tags: javascript, android, css, react-native, gesture

first time posting.

I am creating a kind of popup menu to select a color for a draggable object.
I've created the components and it's all working fine, except for the fact that I can't click the buttons, or nothing happens when I do.

at the moment I am using the package: **'react-native-easy-gestures'** as I was too time-consuming to create the panhandlers myself for this project

Because I am using draggable components, the half circle of colors are positioned around a view that is set to **position: 'absolute'**, and I think that's the problem.

This is my style for the popover component (plus i dynamically set the **top** and **left** positions when mapping through the colors.
and there is of course a higher leveled style for the actual "item" that I can drag which is all placed inside the **Gesture** component from the node modules mentioned above.

```
   button: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        zIndex: 6,
    },
    buttonView: {
        position: 'absolute',
        zIndex: 5,
    },
    popoutMenu: {
        position: 'absolute',
        alignSelf: 'center',
        alignContent: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    },
```

[Screenshot of the menu and item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1zt65.png)

I do believe that the problems lies in how absolute is working. I have the buttons inside their own view at the moment, but I also tried by just having them alone, still, nothing :/

Any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

So I figured it out eventually. First I changed to using the TouchableOpacity from 'react-native-gesture-handler' and then I created a View inside of this touchable that has the dimensions (width and height) of the "button" and it seems to work quite well now.

The problem was as far as I can understand that the touchableXs usually take the style components of their child, so since I didn't really have any children inside of it, the button was just not there.

I also used the one from a different package as it allowed me to set the zIndex of the button without affecting if it is clickable.

At the moment I placed an Icon inside of it, but I am considering removing it and just creating a circle from the view with borderRadius.

Above here is a map function that goes through all my colors from an array.

```
            <View
                key={color}
                style={[
                    styles.button,
                    {
                        top: coords.y - buttonSize / 2,
                        right: coords.x - buttonSize / 2,
                        height: buttonSize,
                        width: buttonSize,
                        padding: 5,
                        borderRadius: buttonSize,
                        // backgroundColor: 'red',
                    },
                ]}>
                <TouchableOpacity
                    color={color}
                    onPress={() => {
                        !isExitButton
                            ? !isResetButton
                                ? setTintColor(color)
                                : setTintColor(null)
                            : setPopoutActive(false);
                    }}>
                    <View
                        style={[
                            styles.circleInTouchable,
                            {
                                width: buttonSize,
                                height: buttonSize,
                            },
                        ]}>
                        <Icon
                            name={'circle'}
                            solid
                            size={buttonSize}
                            color={color}
                        />
                    </View>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

Import TouchableOpacity from react-native-gesture-handler instead react-native.

```
import { TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native-gesture-handler'
```